# A little different version of str_replace

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm looking for a function to replace a certain combination of symbols with values given from array.

Example:

```
$array = array('Tom','Smith');
$string = 'My first name is %% and my last name is %%';

var_dump(str_replace('%%', $array, $string));
```

Expected result is

> My first name is Tom and my last name is Smith

but I get

> My first name is Array and my last name is Array

I suppose if I put `array('%%','%%')` as the first parameter for `str_replace` I would get correct output but I may not always know how many elements there will be in the array so I'm looking for a function that only needs the replace sequence once and replaces each occurrence with each subsequent array element. Is there such a function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this, simply use the [vsprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) function.

```
var_dump(vsprintf('My first name is %s and my last name is %s', $array)
```

each `%s` represent a string. you should read the [format part of this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) to understand why it is `%s` and what else it could be